# The Foot of a Perpendicular from a Point to a Line

Tags: geometry, barycentric-coordinates

I have a triangle $ABC$ and a point $P$ with barycentric coordinates $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ that I want to know the barycentric coordinates of the foot of a perpendicular from P to a line $l: ux + vy + wz = 0$

Comment: Any information of $u,v,w$?

Comment: I'm looking for a general answer, but I'm interested L being the Euler line and P being B